# access query value from function_score to compute new score

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless

I need to customize ES score. The score function I need to implement is:

`score = len(document_term) - len(query_term)`

For instance, one of my document in the ES index is :

```
{
  "name": "foobar"
}
```

And the search query

```
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "match": {
          "name": {
            "query": "foo"
          }
        }
      },
      "functions": [
        {
          "script_score": {
            "script": {
              "source": "doc['name'].value.length() - ?LEN(query_tem)?"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "boost_mode": "replace"
    }
  }
}
```

The above search should provide a score of 6 - 3 = 3. But I didn't find a solution to get access the value of the query term.

Is it possible to access the value of the query term in a function_score context ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct way to do this, however you can achieve that in the below way where you would need to add the query parameters in *two* *different* *parts* of the query.

Before that one important note, you cannot apply the `doc['myfield'].value` if the field is of type [`text`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/text.html), instead you would need to have its sibling field created as [`keyword`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/keyword.html) and refer that in the script, which again I've mentioned below:

### Mapping:

```
PUT myindex
{
  "mappings" : {
    "properties" : {
      "myfield" : {
        "type" : "text",
        "fields" : {
          "keyword" : {
            "type" : "keyword",
            "ignore_above" : 256
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Sample Document:

```
POST myquery/_doc/1
{
  "myfield": "I've become comfortably numb"
}
```

### Query:

```
POST <your_index_name>/_search
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "match": {
          "myfield": "numb"
        } 
      },
      "functions": [
        {
          "script_score": {
            "script": {
              "source": "return doc['myfield.keyword'].value.length() - params.myquery.length()",
              "params": {
                "myquery": "numb"          <---- Add the query string here as well
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "boost_mode": "replace"
    }
  }
}
```

### Response:

```
{
  "took" : 558,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 1,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 24.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "myindex",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 24.0,
        "_source" : {
          "myfield" : "I've become comfortably numb"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!